Is there a tool for generating nanotube from an arbitrary 2D structure?
I'm working on creating a specific nanotube structure with a non-hexagonal surface lattice. I have the 2D structure of the walls (basically a 3-atom-width structure, alike, but not, a layer of MoS2) which I need to "roll up". I'm finding it surprisingly hard to find a tool that could do this tough.
Pretty much all nanotube builders I've found so far generate nanotubes from strach, and are limited to hexagonal surface structure. Is there a tool I could use to create a nanotube from an already defined arbitrary 2D lattice structure?

Chiraltube

... In this paper we present Chiraltube, an open-source Python code that allows the quick generation of a complete NT with any chirality from the unit cell of its original 2D material. We explain the inner workings of the code as well as the theoretical background on which it is built, generalizing concepts from the construction of chiral and achiral carbon NTs to work on any other 2D material. We show various examples of the resulting chiral NT structures built from phosphorene, MoS2 and Ti3C2, and present some analysis on the interatomic distortion in the outermost layers of these NTs, as well as the results of ab initio electronic structure calculations on a set of phosphorene NTs generated by the program, showing the immediate practicality and usefulness of the program. We also explore some limitations and details of the tool as well as further work to be done.

It has a web interface: http://chiraltube.com/ where you can generate nanotubes for different materials like graphene, boron-nitride, silicene, $\ce{MoS2}$, phosphorene, biphenylene, and $\ce{Ti3C2}$:

The full (open access) manuscript is:

José M. de Albornoz-Caratozzolo and Felipe Cervantes-Sodi, Chiraltube, rolling 2D materials into chiral nanotubes, Nanoscale Adv. 6, 79-91, 2024. DOI: 10.1039/D3NA00301A.

And the Github repository is here.
